# Display Custom Fields Under Product Title in WordPress Custom Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Woocommerce Offers hooks to add custom fields to shop page, like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_fields', 5 );
```

This is working fine on the shop page. Can we do the same on the custom product page?

Suppose, I created a page for pre-order products. How can I Use these hooks there?

I used this hook and create a function to display the number of pre-orders. It is working fine on shop page. I want to add the same on any page. Any guide on how to do that?

Here is an image of what I want to achieve (Order Progress Preview):

[image]

Comment: WooCommerce template hooks, only work on WooCommerce pages. If you use [WooCommerce `[products]` shortcode](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#products) to display your products on that custom page, you will be able to use some of those WooCommerce hooks too.

Comment: _"Suppose, I created a page for pre-order products."_ - and that would mean what, _exactly_? Are you talking about a custom page template, something that even makes its own database queries perhaps; or just a page that displays these products based on any shortcodes, or ... something else altogether?